# How get rid of broken images if not loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have displayed images in a grid, but there are some images which are not loaded, so I am getting broken images from [themoviedb.org](https://themoviedb.org).

So, how can I get rid of broken images and keep only those images that are loaded?

Please try to run my code in device for better output.

My code includes HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Please go through my code. Help would be appreciated...

```js
 






 //APIS
const API_KEY='d0bb61e85a438ea9d517dce9f15693aa';
const url='https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=d0bb61e85a438ea9d517dce9f15693aa';
const IMAGE_URL = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500';
```

```css
   
    .header-fixed {
        background-color:#292c2f;
        box-shadow:0 1px 1px #ccc;
        padding: 20px 40px;
        height: 80px;
        color: #ffffff;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        top:-100px;

        -webkit-transition:top 0.3s;
        transition:top 0.3s;

    }

    .header-fixed .header-limiter {
        max-width: 1200px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: grid;
    }

    /*  The header placeholder. It is displayed when the header is fixed to the top of the
        browser window, in order to prevent the content of the page from jumping up. */

    .header-fixed-placeholder{
        height: 80px;
        display: none;
    }

    /* Logo */

    .header-fixed .header-limiter h1 {
        float: left;
        font: normal 28px Cookie, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: 40px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .header-fixed .header-limiter h1 span {
        color: #5383d3;
    }

    /* The navigation links */

    .header-fixed .header-limiter a {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .header-fixed .header-limiter nav {
        font:16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        line-height: 40px;
        float: right;
    }

    .header-fixed .header-limiter nav a{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 5px;
        text-decoration:none;
        color: #ffffff;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    .header-fixed .header-limiter nav a:hover{
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .header-fixed .header-limiter nav a.selected {
        color: #608bd2;
        pointer-events: none;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    /* Fixed version of the header */

    body.fixed .header-fixed {
        padding: 10px 40px;
        height: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    body.fixed .header-fixed-placeholder {
        display: block;
    }

    body.fixed .header-fixed .header-limiter h1 {
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

    body.fixed .header-fixed .header-limiter nav {
        line-height: 28px;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    /* Form */
    .form-group{
        display: grid;
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        margin-left: 1em;
        margin-right: 1em;
        height: 30px;
    }

    #search{
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #5383d3;
        min-height: 38px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1rem;
        line-height: 1.5;
        padding: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }
    .submit_se{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height:30px;
    }
    #inputValue{
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 2px solid gray;
        text-align: center;
    }
    input[type="text"]::placeholder {  
                      
        /* Firefox, Chrome, Opera */ 
        text-align: center; 
    } 

    .card {
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 2px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(6,1fr);
        margin-left: 1em;
        margin-right: 1em;
    }

    .movie_card img {
        width:500px;
    }
    /* Making the header responsive */

    @media all and (max-width: 600px) {

        .header-fixed {
            padding: 20px 0;
            height: 75px;
        }

        .header-fixed .header-limiter h1 {
            float: none;
            margin: -8px 0 10px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 24px;
            line-height: 1;
        }

        .header-fixed .header-limiter nav {
            line-height: 1;
            float:none;
        }

        .header-fixed .header-limiter nav a {
            font-size: 13px;
        }

        body.fixed .header-fixed {
            display: none;
        }

    }

    /*
         We are clearing the body's margin and padding, so that the header fits properly.
         We are also adding a height to demonstrate the scrolling behavior. You can remove
         these styles.
     */

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 1500px;
    }
    .title{
            text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
   
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--my javascript is in my html-->
    <!--my javascript include the APIs-->
    <!--YOU CAN TRY MY CODE FOR BETTER OUTPUT-->
    <!--I CANNOT FIX THE BROKEN IMAGES DISPLAYED IN GRID-->
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Movie app</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header-fixed">
            <div class="header-limiter">
            <h1 class="title" >MOVIE TRAILERS</h1>
        </div>
        </header>
        <div class="container">
            <form>
                 <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="inputValue" placeholder="search the trailer">
            </div>
            <div class="submit_se">
            <button type="submit" id="search">Search the movie trailer</button>
            
           
    
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="movies-searchable">
    
        </div>
    
    <!--JAVASCRIPT CODE-->
    <script>
                
        //selecting DOM elements
        const buttonElement = document.querySelector('#search');
        const inputElement = document.querySelector('#inputValue');
        const movieSearchable= document.querySelector('#movies-searchable');
        
      
        
    //function1
    buttonElement.onclick =function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const value =  inputElement.value;
        const newUrl = url + '&query=' + value;
    fetch(newUrl)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            //data.result[]
            const movies = data.results;
           const movieBlock = createMovieContainer(movies);
           movieSearchable.appendChild(movieBlock);
        console.log('Data:',data);
    })
        .catch((error)=>{
        console.log('Error',error)
    });
    console.log(value);
    }
    
    
    
    //function 3 
    function movieSection(movies){
        return movies.map((movie) => {
             return `
           
               <img src=${IMAGE_URL + movie.poster_path} data-movie-id=${movie.id}/>
             `
             ;
         })
        }
        function onError(img) {
            if(img=='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500'){
        // Change the url
        img.src = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500';
        jQuery(img).hide();
            }
    }
       
    
       
         //function2
     function createMovieContainer(movies){
         const movieElement =document.createElement('div');
         movieElement.setAttribute('class','movie');
         const movieTemplate = `
         <h2 class="text-center">Search results </h2>
             <div class="card movie_card">
         ${movieSection(movies)} 
       
                <i class="fas fa-play play_button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Play  Trailer">
                </i>
                <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                    <span class="movie_info"></span>
                    <span class="movie_info float-right"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         `;
         movieElement.innerHTML = movieTemplate;
         return movieElement;
     } 
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 1. Why is the complete text in bold? 2. That's too much code (-> [mcve]); 3. Putting everything in the HTML section of the snippet editor _might_ work but is not how it is intended to be used (-> [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)); 4. You should never post any API keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want something displayed even when there's no image you could provide a fallback value to a placeholder image:

```
const path = movie.poster_path || pathToKnownPlaceholder
...
<img src=${IMAGE_URL + path} data-movie-id=${movie.id}/>
```

If you want the item removed you'll want to use `.filter` before applying `.map`. Looking at the returned data it looks like non-existent `poster_path`s return `null`, so:

```
movies.filter((movie) => movie.poster_path !== null).map((movie) => {
  return `
    <img src=${IMAGE_URL + movie.poster_path} data-movie-id=${movie.id}/>
  `;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your onclick function.

All of your broken images ends with `/w500null` so you just filter all `img` tags and do something with it, in my example set it to display none.

```
var broken="/w500null";

const img = document.querySelectorAll("img");
//get all images
//console.log(img);
img.forEach(img => {
    if (img.src.endsWith(broken)) {
      img.style.display = "none";
    };    
});
```

Your on click function should look like:

```
buttonElement.onclick =function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const value =  inputElement.value;
        const newUrl = url + '&query=' + value;
    fetch(newUrl)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            //data.result[]
            const movies = data.results;
           const movieBlock = createMovieContainer(movies);
           movieSearchable.appendChild(movieBlock);
           var broken="/w500null";

const img = document.querySelectorAll("img");
//get all links
//console.log(img);
img.forEach(img => {
    if (img.src.endsWith(broken)) {
      img.style.display = "none";
    };    
});
        //console.log('Data:',data);
    })
        .catch((error)=>{
        //console.log('Error',error)
    });
    //console.log(value);
    //
    //
    }
```